# Prevent android project to load native library

Tags: android, security, java-native-interface

Reverse engineering is a great problem for android apk. Anyone can easily generate code from apk file using dex2jar and jd. Proguard can gives little bit security by changing the variable/method name. Problem is .so file. As an example, i have a so file which has a encrypt and decrypt  method in it. If someone get my apk then he can easily get the so file and by creating a new project with same package name (not hidden in native loading class) he can use the functions without any problem.

Is there any solution to prevent this?? Is there any way so that i can identify my project from native code and reject the request if it comes from invalid project? Eclipse sign the apk with a key-store and password. Can i check the sign information from native code??

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents are that `Proguard` is just a basic obfuscator(till a point). There are many other services/tools(which might not be completely free) but do good obfuscation, app integrity protection, Tamper detection and Tamper defence etc. Check out [Arxan](http://www.arxan.com/solutions/mobile-app-protection/) and [DashO Pro](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/features). 
You might try to use them for more protection. They even work with rooted devices. Hope this helps in someway.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

This is a classic problem with any intermediary bytecode language: JVM languages (Java, Groovy, Akka, etc.), CLR languages (C#, ASP.NET, etc.) and more. Since the procedures to compile the source code to its intermediary bytecode are well-documented and fairly straight-forward, it isn't all that difficult to reverse engineer the bytecode back into source.

As @Shobhit Puri has already pointed out, a good obfuscator will *help* deter most would-be attackers from expending the energy to decompile your bytecode. But any determined attacker with enough skills will be able to reverse engineer any obfuscated code (please note that there are many high quality [Java de-obfuscators](https://www.google.com/#q=java+deobfuscator) out there...) you can generate.

#### So how does one mitigate this?

Your best bet is to store any sensititve resources or business logic on the server, **and have the client (your Android app) access those resources or invoke that business logic in a defensive way**. By "defensive", I mean you code the client in such a way that any attacker who successfully obtained your full source code wouldn't be able to ascertain anything meaningful with it.

For instance, instead of:

```
// Get password from user input:
String password = getUserInput();

// Make sure password is correct.
if(password.equals("12345") {
    // Grant access to the system
} else {
    throw new SecurityException("Blah whatever");
}
```

You have this:

```
// Get password from user input:
String password = getUserInput();

// Make sure password is correct.
String correctPassword = passwordService.fetchFromServer();
if(password.equals(correctPassword) {
    // Grant access to the system
} else {
    throw new SecurityException("Blah whatever");
}
```

If an attacker were to get access to your source code, and you provide access to the password somewhere on the client-side (even if its encrypted), eventually they'll figure out how to break in. But if you fetch the magical password from the server, and never reference its value anywhere on the client, then they now need to break into your server to get access to it.

Then all you have to do is properly secure your app server, and for that you have excellent prospects like:

- [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/)
- [OWASP ESAPI](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/)
- [Webcastellum WAF](http://www.webcastellum.org/)
- [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
- ...and countless more; welcome to the world of [websec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security)

Note that in my code example above, ultimately there is no perfect defense against a skilled-enough attacker. For instance, a skilled attacker could sniff the network traffic between the client and the server during the time that the `passwordService#fetchFromServer()` call was made. If the password is returned as plaintext, voila - they have it. Even if the password is returned using SSL or some other strong encryption, your client will need to store or access the private key for that encryption somewhere locally. Once they have the private key, they'll be able to access the password. All this to say:

> There is no such thing as perfect security. There is no such thing as an unhackable system. **The purpose of your security should be to make the cost of obtaining the resource far greater than the value of the resource itself.**

#### Bottom Line

As a smart developer, you need to *assume* that the attackers will exploit your client application every which way. You need to *assume* that they will eventually gain access to your client's source code, and even understand how it communicates with your server. And on the server-side, you need to *assume* that every request coming from a client is an attack, and treat it as such. This will put you in the right state of mind to code defensively.

What you need to beef up on is server-side security, and that is not trivial by any means. But if you just remember to keep all sensitive code and data on the server, and access it defensively on the client-side, you'll do more to protect your app than any obfuscator can offer you. HTH and happy coding.

Comment: Your suggestion is very helpful. I also thought the fetch info form server/ ssl etc. All options has bad side.